# Is Kreacher ever called 'Monster'?

Tags: harry-potter, names, fan-fiction

Reading some Harry Potter fan-fics, I noticed Kreacher the house elf sometimes being called 'Monster', and even answering to that name, which is something that confuses me.

Is Kreacher called 'Monster' in any of the books? Is it a typo? Is it something that the author of some fics decided to add?

Comment: I believe it is a fanfic addition

Comment: I have read hundreds of fanfics and have never seen Kreacher referred to monster by name. I think it must be specific to a single author.

Comment: I don't think this is unclear. This is just asking whether the books used a certain word. Voted to leave open

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could easily be a translation issue. When translating the books, the names of characters were sometimes changed in an attempt to maintain wordplay, such as Kreacher's name being a homonym of "creature." The Portuguese editions of the Harry Potter books renamed him to "Monstro," which directly translates to Monster. If the fan fiction in question was written by a Portuguese person more familiar with that name or written in Portuguese and then translated it could result in Kreacher being incorrectly referred to by that name.